# Save Multiple Email Attachments For Current Date Only

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. I have prepared one code to download multiple emails' attachments for current date only but whenever I execute this macro, it's giving me:

> Automation Error, The system cannot find the specified path

Can someone look into below pasted code and help me out. Thanks

```
Sub Outlook_Attachments()

Dim OLOOK As Outlook.Application
Dim OMAIL As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim FOL As Outlook.Folder
Dim SFOLDER As String
Dim FNAME As String
Set OLOOK = New Outlook.Application
Set OMAIL = OLOOK.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set ONS = OLOOK.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set FOL = ONS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test")
SFOLDER = "D:\"
FNAME = SFOLDER & Format(Date, "MM/DD/YYYY") & "*"  
For Each OMAIL In FOL.Items
    For Each ATMT In OMAIL.Attachments
        ATMT.SaveAsFile FNAME & ATMT.DisplayName
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Sub Outlook_Attachments()

Dim OLOOK As Outlook.Application
Dim OMAIL As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ONS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim FOL As Outlook.Folder
Dim SFOLDER As String
Dim FNAME As String
Set OLOOK = New Outlook.Application
Set OMAIL = OLOOK.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set ONS = OLOOK.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set FOL = ONS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test")
SFOLDER = "D:\"
FNAME = SFOLDER & Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") & "-"

For Each OMAIL In FOL.Items
    'check email recevied date
    If Format(OMAIL.ReceivedTime, "MM-DD-YYYY") = Format(Date, "MM-DD-YYYY") Then
        For Each ATMT In OMAIL.Attachments
            ATMT.SaveAsFile FNAME & ATMT.DisplayName
        Next
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Using '/' and '*' in file/folder name is forbidden.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback. Code is working now but it's downloading all attachments even for previous dates as well.

Comment: How to get the attachments only for current date.

Comment: You would have to include an IF statement checking what was the email date. Check this link for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/office/vba/api/Outlook.MailItem.ReceivedTime

Comment: I have included the IF statement in my answer. Please make sure to approve the answer if it is correct :) thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Code is working perfectly fine now.

Comment: Dear, is it possible if we can apply Subject filter condition in this code also? Please help.